# Jenkins with make and docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have been playing around with Jenkins, and I'm now able to connect github and set triggers. I want to build my code using make and docker, however when i execute make or docker in the shell, they are not found. How do I configure Jenkins' build step to run make and docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install `make` and the `docker daemon` on your Jenkins server. This will allow you to build and push docker images from within your Jenkins build pipelines using the `Executable Shell` Build task. You will also be able to run `make` commands there as well.

```
docker build -t <USER>/<REPO_NAME>:<TAG> .
docker push <USER>/<REPO_NAME>:<TAG>
```

There are also Jenkins plugins available for building your docker images too.

I would **NOT** recommend running Jenkins using a Docker container, then running Docker inside that container. This is known as Docker in Docker(aka. DinD), and should be avoided for the reasons stated in [this article](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).

Answer (score 1):

You can install Docker on the same machine where your jenkins is running.

Or you can run a docker container which contains both jenkins and docker.

If you purpose is to learn jenkins, I suggest running Jenkins within a docker and Docker daemon on your host machine.

1. just have Docker installed on your host machine.
2. then issue the command which runs

   docker run \
       --rm  -u root -p 8080:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name myjenkinsserver jenkinsci/blueocean

then you are ready to go.

3. add a pipeline job as follows:

   pipeline {
       agent { docker 'gcc:latest' }
       stages {
           stage('build') {
               steps {
                   sh 'make --version'
               }
           }
       }
   }
4. now you can run `make` commands.

In general, it is better to run jenkins jobs on Jenkins slave machines or in other terms, Jenkins agents. You can create custom Jenkins agents which include necessary tools, in your case, such as `make`.